# unable to sign in AZURE AD using "Federated account" IssuerAssignedId as sign in Name/email

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

i have created an account as a **multitenant user using the "federated account"** creating settings following this: [MS documentation for Create Users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp)

code:

```
var user = new Microsoft.Graph.User
        {
            DisplayName = "John Doe",
            Identities = new List<ObjectIdentity>()
                {
                        SignInType = "federated",
                        Issuer = "myOrganizatinName.com.au",
                        IssuerAssignedId = "abc@myOrganizatinName.com.au"
                    }
                },
                            PasswordProfile = new Microsoft.Graph.PasswordProfile
                            {
                                Password = "Officework1",
                                ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false
                            },
                            PasswordPolicies = "DisablePasswordExpiration",
            OtherMails = new List<String>()
            {
                "JohnDoe@gmail.com"
            },
            
        };
```

user is **created successfully**:
but when i see the User in Azure Portal that user is present with only **UserPrincipalName** as: objectId@myTenantDomainname.onmicrosoft.com  only and the email address i provided while creating the user through graph Api is not present anywhere.
and ehen i try to sign in using this email address and password provided in user creating time makes **error of "userName and password is invalid"**
**only the UPN appearing with objectID@@myTenantDomain.onmicrosoft.com is making me success to sign in.**

the question is **how can i sign in using the email address which i provided while creating the user?**

any help in this will be much appriciated.

Comment: If the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Ms Graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to modify the **userPrincipalName** field.

[image]

Comment: You only need to change `objectID@@myTenantDomain.onmicrosoft.com` to the email address you provided when you created the user.